# How can I click a <li> item with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, greasemonkey, userscripts

```
<ul class="myList clearfix" id="thismyList">
    <li class="myBullet" id="answer1">blabla1</li>
    <li class="myBullet" id="answer2">blabla2</li>
    <li class="myBullet" id="answer3">blabla3</li>
</ul>
```

In this page, how can I automatically click item `blabla2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest and most powerful is probably the [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) way (btw - it's one of the few w3 specifications that are actually a very good and helpful read). You can have almost any conditions you want to have.

```
var xresult = document.evaluate("//*[text()='blabla2']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
xresult.singleNodeValue.click();
```

[`evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate), 
[`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click)

[See this doc to know more about XPath in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)

---

The non-XPath way would be to go through all the nodes manually and search for the first one containing the right text:

```
var findElem = function(elems, text) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].textContent == text) {
            return elems[i];
        } else {
            var result = findElem(elems[i].children, text);
            if (result != undefined) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla2").click();
```

Comment: Aha, that's going to be a little more delicate, but still. Wait a sec.

Comment: Thanks for edited answer. I will try it. But I have more than one "blabla2" on page. Will that be a problem?

Comment: How do you then want to determine the right one? By XPath, you can have almost any conditions you want to have.

Comment: Yep. The current version look for the first one :).

Comment: The XPath one should now, too, I forgot a `singleNodeValue` property. I'm glad I could help!